# How to better control sequence of events in code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In the following code, I am using to linkcount to control when things happen.  The problem is, linkcount == 3 is running before linkcount == 2 is finished and errors are happening.  Section three is looking for an element on the web page before the page is loaded.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    linkcount++;

    if (linkcount == 1)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("value", "username");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", "password");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
    }

    if (linkcount == 2)
    {
        HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
        select elem).ElementAt(0);    
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
    }

    if (linkcount == 3)
    {
            webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["ContentFrame"].Document.GetElementById("btn‌​Punch").InvokeMember("Click");
            // string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.InnerText;
            // string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.Body.InnerText;
            // MessageBox.Show(content);
            // link.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of  `GetElementById`. If it's `null`, then the element isn't available.

Comment: Don't you have any way to identify in which step you are by reading some attribute of `webBrowser1.Document` ? For example, if the document contains certain specific text then you are 100% sure that you are in one of the three cases.

Answer (score 0):

I combined @JohnnyMopp's proposition and mine, this is the resulting code.

I could not test it since I don't know the URL, and the solution is heavily dependent on the web content of each one of the three cases, but this should give you an idea of how to implement it:

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName") != null)
        {
            // 1st case:
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("value", "username");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", "password");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
        }
        else if (webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["ContentFrame"].Document.GetElementById("btn‌​Punch") != null)
        {
            // 3rd case:
            webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["ContentFrame"].Document.GetElementById("btn‌​Punch").InvokeMember("Click");
            //                string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.InnerText;
            //                string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.Body.InnerText;
            //                MessageBox.Show(content);
            //                link.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
        else
        {
            // 2nd case:
            HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
                select elem).ElementAt(0);
            link.InvokeMember("Click");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to look for the "btnPunch" element in all frames?  I am evidently looking in the wrong place...

Comment: My guess is directly using `Document.GetElementById("btn‌​Punch")`.